# How group data together in an array and combine the values of a linked column (income)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have the following table:

[image]

I would like to:

Group the data based on Segment.

Combine the values in income to produce a % of total income for that segment.

My desired result in this case would be

```
Segment      | Total Income |  Ratio |  Size  | CAGR
------------------------------------------------------------------
Football     |    10,000    |    7%  |   12   |    9
Transport    |    70,000    |   47%  |   20   |    8
Rail         |    70,000    |   47%  |   30   |   15
```

The structure of my `customers` array is:

```
[{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Company A",
 "income": 10000,
 "industry": "Sport",
 "segment": "Football",
 "marketsize": 12,
 "cagr": 9
},
{...}
]
```

My approach is to first use .reduce() to calculate the total income, for the ratio. I have done this below, which outputs 150000.  I can use this to work out my ratio's.

```
totalIncome(){
      const newtotal = this.customers.reduce((total, amount) => 
         total + amount.income, 0
      )
      return newtotal
    }
```

Now, I wish to group the segments together and combine the values of the income field? How do I do this?

Comment: Can you post a demo with your current attempt at solving the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below solution should solve your problem.

```js
const data = [{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Company A",
 "income": 10000,
 "industry": "Sport",
 "segment": "Football",
 "marketsize": 12,
 "cagr": 9
},
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Company B",
 "income": 20000,
 "industry": "Engineering",
 "segment": "Transport",
 "marketsize": 20,
 "cagr": 8
},
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Company C",
 "income": 50000,
 "industry": "Engineering",
 "segment": "Transport",
 "marketsize": 20,
 "cagr": 8
},
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "Company D",
 "income": 70000,
 "industry": "Engineering",
 "segment": "Rail",
 "marketsize": 30,
 "cagr": 15
}
]

const totalIncome = data.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.income, 0);

const segments = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const totalSegmentIncome = (acc[item.segment] ? acc[item.segment].totalIncome : 0) + item.income;
  acc[item.segment] = {
    segment: item.segment,
    totalIncome: totalSegmentIncome,
    ratio: totalSegmentIncome / totalIncome,
    size: item.marketsize,
    cagr: item.cagr
  };
  return acc;
}, {});

const segmentsAsArray = Object.keys(segments).map(k => segments[k]);

console.log(segments);
console.log(segmentsAsArray);
```